# Criar várias colunas de Lis dinâmicas com flex-direction: column; deixando o primeiro filho com width proporcional a quantidade de colunas

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Objetivo: Criar várias colunas dinâmicas de `li`s, mais o primeiro filho tem que ter o `width` de `100%`.

Problema: O primeiro filho está quebrando todas as colunas de `li`s

```
----------------------------------------
               FILHO 1
----------------------------------------
FILHO 2  |  FILHO 7    |   FILHO 12
FILHO 3  |  FILHO 8    |   FILHO 13
FILHO 4  |  FILHO 9    |   FILHO 14
FILHO 5  |  FILHO 10   |   FILHO 15
FILHO 6  |  FILHO 11   |   FILHO 16
----------------------------------------
```

```css
.pai {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  min-width: 455px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
}

.pai .filho {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

pai li {
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 225px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class="pai">
  <li class="filho"><a>teste1</a></li>
  <li><a>teste2</a></li>
  <li><a>teste3</a></li>
  <li><a>teste4</a></li>
  <li><a>teste5</a></li>
  <li><a>teste6</a></li>
  <li><a>teste7</a></li>
  <li><a>teste9</a></li>
  <li><a>teste10</a></li>
  <li><a>teste11</a></li> 
  <li><a>teste12</a></li>
  <li><a>teste13</a></li>
  <li><a>teste14</a></li>
  <li><a>teste15</a></li> 
  <li><a>teste16</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Este tamanho que você cita é o width? E os itens já estão abaixo dos outros, no caso você quis dizer as colunas?, o fórum é em portugues mas se você for citar propriedades é melhor não traduzir

Comment: Ola, obrigado pela sujestão, então, o tamanho se refere ao width do pai. Com relação ao layout eu preciso que as Lis se agrupem em colunas dinâmicas, porém o first-child "filho" tem que acompanhar o width de todas as colunas de Lis formadas na horizontal, no formato do desenho que eu criei acima,

Answer (score 0):

Bem, pelo que entendi você quer um container que tenha no máximo 3 filhos por linha você pode fazer isso utilizando grid layout mas também pode usar o flex-box puro.
abaixo vou dar um exemplo de como fazer.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;

  justify-content: center;
}

.container .child {
  flex: 1 1 calc(33.3% - 40px);
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 4%;
  background-color: #548;
  color: #FFFFFF;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    .child 1
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    .child 2
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    .child 3
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    .child 4
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    .child 5
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    .child 6
  </div>
</div>
```

com esse código você vai criar um container que aceita divide cada linha em 3 filhos.
clicando no botão executar você consegue obter o resultado do código.

Comment: Olá luciano, infelizmente essa forma não atente, pois se trata de um menu, vou reformular a pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Seu documento HTML está quebrado, você não fechou nenhuma das tags `<li>` corretamente.
Mude o valor da propriedade `flex-direction` da classe "pai" para `row`

Comment: Muito obrigado pela correção, infelizmente o atributo row não resolve o problema, preciso que as lis fiquem aninhadas na vertical, e o row aninha na horizontal da esquerda pra direita.

Answer (score 0):

A melhor maneira de você determinar o tamanho relativo do flex item sem alterar o cálculo e fluxo dos demais, é com [flex-basis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis). O flex-basis é relativo ao `flex-direction`, se a direção for **column sera o height**, e se for **row sera o width** do elemento pai com `display flex`. Dito isso você só pode determinar o tamanho do `filho` em linha com `flex-direction row`, ainda assim você pode ter colunas nos demais itens com wrap:

```css
.pai {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  min-width: 455px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
}

.pai .filho {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.pai li {
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 225px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class="pai">
  <li class="filho"><a>teste1</a></li>
  <li><a>teste2</a></li>
  <li><a>teste3</a></li>
  <li><a>teste4</a></li>
  <li><a>teste5</a></li>
  <li><a>teste6</a></li>
  <li><a>teste7</a></li>
  <li><a>teste9</a></li>
  <li><a>teste10</a></li>
  <li><a>teste11</a></li> 
  <li><a>teste12</a></li>
  <li><a>teste13</a></li>
  <li><a>teste14</a></li>
  <li><a>teste15</a></li> 
  <li><a>teste16</a></li>
</ul>
```